# Implement function avg() that takes as input a list that contains lists of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out how to do my homework at all and it's stressing me out:

Implement function avg() that takes as input a list that contains lists of numbers. Each number list represents the grades a particular student received for a course. For example, here is an input list for a class of four students:

```
[[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]
```

The function avg should print, one per line, every student’s average grade. You may assume that every list of grades is nonempty, but you may not assume that every student has the same number of grades.

```
avg ([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])

90.0

60.0

87.0

11.0
```

I'm completely lost and I know I'm not even close to finding the answer. This is what I've done so far

```
def avg(grades):
      return avg(grades)
 grades =[INSERT LIST OF RANDOM NUMBER]
 avg(grades)
```

Yes, I know that this isn't even close and I have the brain the size of a pea. I can't figure it out. Can anyone please help me and explain it in a way that an idiot would understand? This is only the first problem. It's supposed to be the easiest but I can't do it.

The homework is due in a few hours, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you know you'll need to process each student in turn, right?

```
def avg(list_of_students):
    for student in list_of_students:
        ...
```

You can see how many grades the student has with `length = len(students)`.

You can add up that student's grade with `total = sum(students)`.

Hey, that looks a lot like the stuff you'll need in order to calculate the average, doesnt it? And then you're supposed to `print(` the `average` value `)`, right?

I think those are the pieces of the puzzle that you're missing, aren't they?

Comment: What I like is how you graciously put the pieces out there, without completing the homework. This way, it's their work and not *plagiarised*.

Comment: You've got a lot of patience dude.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help and explanation. I honestly can't thank you enough.

Comment: @user8772789 Sure, you can thank me: study hard and master this stuff so that I can hire you in a few years. See you then!

Comment: @AAA Thanks. I wanted to nudge them in the right direction but still have them do the work and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

`[avg(lst) for lst in myList]` where `myList = [[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]` will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easily  with list methods. "sum" is one the methods in list(array) which returns summation of all the elements in a  list."len" is another method in list which returns length of all the elements in a list. The code is shown below

```
x=[[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]
for i in x:
    print(sum(i)/len(i))
```

Or you can try with list comprehension as shown below

```
x=[[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]]
print("".join(["{}\n".format(sum(i)/len(i)) for i in x]))
```